# URxvt: vim and cursorColor [invisible cursor or invisible cursor text]

Tags: vim, terminal, colors, xterm, urxvt

**Introduction**

I've always used a light-background terminal and a dark-background editor (`vim`). On this I'm not willing to compromise. In any case, I've just switched from `xterm` to `urxvt` ($TERM == rxvt-unicode-256color) mainly to due an unresolved fontconfig/xft font truncation bug in xterm, and urxvt's ability to reflow text properly (there are other perks though, so please don't blindly suggest switching terminals). Unfortunately I have one problem with urxvt that I can't solve: the cursor color in vim is invisible. Let me explain with each terminal's default behaviour:

XTerm:

- cursor color defaults to the foreground color of the underlying text, and therefore varies. If there is no underlying text, it defaults to the foreground color (white or black, usually)
- text color under cursor is pulled to the background color (black or white, usually)
- XTerm ignores a cursorColor setting of "#000000" and instead uses default behaviour

Therefore, text under the cursor is only invisible in XTerm when the cursor color matches (as near as possible) the background color.

URxvt:

- cursor color defaults to black.
- text color under cursor is pulled to white.

Therefore, text under the cursor is only invisible in URxvt when the cursor color is white

**Back to the problem:**

The URxvt cursor is invisible in vim because I use a dark colorscheme (black cursor on black background). I can't change the cursor to color to white in `~/.Xdefaults` because I use a light-background terminal, this would lead to a white cursor in a white background over white text: both invisible cursor and invisible font. However, while vim normally doesn't support changing the cursor color, with a [little bit of hackery in `~/.vimrc`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor) it becomes possible. Unfortunately, a white or lighter-colored cursor leads to either invisible text or at least much less legible text.

**Overview**

Invisible Cursor:

- explanation: black cursor on black background.
- solution: change cursor color to white (or a lighter color)
- problem: leads to invisible text (or harder to read text)

Invisible Text:

- explanation: white cursor over white text
- solution: ????

**Solutions**

I'm hoping either that URxvt can support XTerm's cursorColor/cursorTextColor behaviour, or at least support modifying the color of the text under the cursor, though of course I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: Did you try setting the cursor color to "reverse"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `-xrm "*cursorColor: reverse"` -> `urxvt: unable to parse color 'reverse', using pink instead.`

Comment: Well, the urxvt-specific resource is `cursorColor2`, with such a nondescript name no wonder I didn't originally find it. Unfortunately it seems incompatible with the vim hack because I have yet to find a corresponding escape sequence.

Comment: And the reset sequence in the vim hack doesn't actually work with urxvt.

Comment: Yes, urxvt doesn't seem to care at all about vim's `cterm=reverse`. That's unfortunate.

Comment: Most likely `cterm` is unsupported by XTerm, rather vim sends an escape sequence to the terminal, and in this particular instance `reverse` is unsupported by URxvt. Do you know which escape sequence or resource vim's `reverse` sets? Perhaps I'll add support to URxvt. I'm also considering adding support for XTerm's dynamic color reset OSC sequences and extended them to URxvt's cursorColor2 as well (relatively easy; the problem is no one responds).